# How to keep leading to font size proportions when scaling text in indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography

So, my text is at 12pt with 20.8 leading. I want to scale the text up, and keep the leading proportionate, as increasing font size closes the gap that the leading makes.

Answer (score 1):

### Set the leading in percentage

- Calculate the leading in percentage:
  `12 pt / 20.8` = `12 pt / 145%`
- Select the text and set the leading to auto
- Increase the font size
- Change the leading to 145%

[image: leading in percentage]

Comment: I had forgotten you could set leading as a percentage. Your first bullet is a bit misleading though - you don't tell the whole story. 20.8 isn't 145% of 12. When you enter a percentage in the leading field you get the the entered percentage of the *leading*, not the *font size*. When you choose *auto* the leading is (by default, but not necessarily) set to 120% of the font size (120% of 12 = 14.4). Then you can find that 20.8 is about 145% of 14.4 (more precisely 20.8 / 14.4 = 144.4444...%). Do you see what I mean?

Comment: You are right. Thinking OP already knows this helped me writing a shorter answer. 

Comment: Assuming people know things can be dangerous. Anyway this answer inspired me to another (better? ) answer for this question.

Comment: This is a world of assumptions. I'm always glad to be an inspiration 

Comment: I'm a 'splainer. 

Answer (score 0):

Grab a corner of the text box while holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and drag.

This scales the text box up or down proportionally, meaning, font size and leading will be both adjusted proportionally.

Then re-adjust the text box to its original size by dragging the side handles, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

A hands-on way of doing this is simply to multiply the *Font Size* and the *Leading* with the same number:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to scale the *Leading* proportionally with the *Font Size* using "Auto Leading*:

- Select your text frame or paragraph.
- Enter *Justification* in the "sandwich menu" in the *Paragraph* panel (or in your *Paragraph Style* settings).
- In the *Auto Leading* field write: `100 * Leading / Font Size` (in your case `100*20.8/12`).
- Set the leading to *Auto*.

Now you can change the *Font Size* and the *Leading* will keep the initial ratio.

[image]